# How to parsing active session id as foreign key in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I got two tables in database called **user** [user table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwhjV.jpg) and **fileupload** [fileupload table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bikwB.jpg). I've managed to input data to **user** table with its auto increment primary key, and now I'm attempting to insert **fileupload** table with foreign key from **user** table. **fileupload** is useful for saving data from uploaded file and it'll use `ID_USER` session from **user** table as a foreign key in **fileupload** table.
Here's my controller:

```
function do_upload() {

    $config['upload_path'] = './file_upload/'; 
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'xls|xlsx';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config); 

    if($this->upload->do_upload("file")){ 
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data(), 
                      'id_user' => $this->session->userdata('ID_USER'));

        $title= $this->input->post('judul'); 
        $filename= $data['upload_data']['file_name']; 
        $id_user = $data['id_user']['ID_USER']; 

        $result= $this->M_dbstatmanagement->simpan_upload($title, $filename, $id_user); 
        echo json_decode($result);
    }
}
```

here's the model:

```
function simpan_upload($title, $filename, $id_user) {
    $data = array(
        'TITLE' => $title, 
        'NAMA_FILE' => $filename, 
        'ID_USER' => $id_user 
    );
    return $this->db->insert('fileupload', $data); 
}
```

and here's the upload form [upload form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBmJT.jpg)

When I click upload button in upload form, nothing happen. And when I check the **fileupload** table, no data was inserted.

Comment: please use the ```echo($this->db->last_query() );``` in ```simpan_upload()``` before ```return```. it's show you insert query.

Comment: you can save session in  table in database.and relation to other tables.

Comment: @hamedhossani Do I need to erase `$result`? So it'll `return` directly to `$this->db->insert('fileupload', $data);`

Comment: @hamedhossani Hey it works with `$this->db->last_query();`. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use 
`$this->db->last_query();` in `simpan_upload()` before return.
 it's show you insert query and you can correct it.

It will be determined that the `ID_USER` has been sent.